# Pulling date and time values from excel (CSV) to C#

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I’m building a application that monitors information on a website.
The website allows you to save stuff off it as a CSV.

My problem arises when I try to pull time and date information from Excel.

For those who want to see what spreadsheet I am working on:
http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/ip/Market/Reports/CSMPriceReportServlet?contentType=html

if you want the spreadsheet:
change the html in the link to csv

I’m having trouble with A6 downward and B6 downward column.

When I pull out the A6 column, the dynamic type is string.
My question regarding this part is:
Is there any way I can parse the string into a DateTime so I can format it in a standard way?

When I pull out the B6 column, the dynamic type for the time (HH:MM:SS AM/PM) becomes double.
Is there any way I can parse the double into a DateTime so I can format it in a standard way as well?

Thanks so much for your time you guys!

Cheers,
-Jeremiah Tantongco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses!
I did some more digging and was able to solve both my issues.

For parsing a custom time formatted string into a datetime in C#, use:

DateTime.ParseExact(yourString, formatString, null);

format string is the scheme of your custom time formatted string

Ex:
"09/17/2009 14" becomes "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy HH"

For converting datetime from excel that is stored as a double, use:

DateTime.FromOADate(yourDouble);

Answer (score 1):

Get .Text rather than .Value

Answer (score 0):

if the file format is static then you can pull the data as string in first place say a5 + ":" + a6 (09/16/2009 16:15:00)  reformate it as per your requirements and save is as datatime